# raising 404 when the url doesnt exist

Tags: django

I have a set of url patterns in django 1.4.1. I want to be able to raise 404 when the user tries a url[users do that] thats not in the list.

Not sure how to do it. May be I am not reading the docs right.

PS: i have set DEBUG to False in settings, and any try at invalid urls say "An error has occured at the server"

Thanks and regards
Prabhakar S

Answer (score 4):

You need to write `404.html` template, which django uses to show *page not found* error when you set `DEBUG=False`.

Similarly, you may want to write `500.html` to handle any server errors.

More reference : [Writing 404 view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view)